# Web Api C# .net params POST

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to send a list of products for my web api in C# via JavaScript but my API doesn't accepts the products. How do I should pass it?

This is my model

```
public class ProductModels
{
    public int productId { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal amount { get; set; }
}
```

and my API endpoint

```
    [Route("api/pag_seguro/transactions/credit_card")]
    public IHttpActionResult DoTransactionWithCreditCard(ProductModels[] products, string senderHash, string cardHash)
```

in Javascript I'm trying to send it like this

```
data.products = [{ "productId": 1, "description": "tupperware", "quantity": 1, "amount": 29.80 }];

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url + '/api/pag_seguro/transactions/credit_card?cardHash=' + cardHash + '&senderHash=' + senderHash,
    data: data,
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false
});
```

and still about this endpoint... how do I send the senderHash and cardHash as POST parameters so that than doesn't appears in web url?

Thank you all

Comment: Why not make a complex object with everything in it (including products array, card hash and sender hash)?

Comment: I can not send an object to api, or at least I am doing it wrong, as it is being shown above. Otherwise, it would be right to ship the ProductModels. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the content type in the request as

```
contentType:"application/json"
```

Also, use `JSON.stringify` to convert the data to JSON format when you send.

Try this code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url + '/api/pag_seguro/transactions/credit_card?cardHash=' + cardHash + '&senderHash=' + senderHash,
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public IHttpActionResult DoTransactionWithCreditCard([FromUri] SiteInfo, siteInfoProductModels[] products)
```

and your siteinfo model is

```
public class SiteInfo
    {
        public string senderHash { get; set; }
        public string cardHash { get; set; }
    }
```

finally remove your route from action header and add new route in webapiconfig.cs like this (and change js file set params liek this /param1/param1 )

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "HashRoute",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{senderHash}/{cardHash}"
);
```